# Dataflow template that reads input and schema from GCS as runtime arguments

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a custom dataflow template that takes 3 runtime arguments. An input file and schema file location from gcs and bigquery datasink table.

The input file seems to be read properly using the `beam.io.textio.ReadFromText` method. However, I need to feed the schema file (instead of hard-coding it inside the template by reading that from gcs as well.

This schema also needs to be passed to `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`

This is my first time working with Dataflow and I am struggling to make it work. Any ideas on how do I read a gcs location as string when the location is provided as a runtime param (knowing that get() on run time param fails when pushing the Dataflow template).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging
import os

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json

class TemplateOptions(PipelineOptions):
  """ Class to parse runtime options as required for templating the pipeline """
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--input_file',
      dest='input_file',
      type=str,
      required=False,
      help='Google Storage Bucket location of Input file',
      default=''
    )

    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--input_file_schema',
      dest='input_file_schema',
      type=str,
      required=False,
      help='Google Storage Bucket location of Input file schema',
      default=''
    )

    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--bq_table_name',
      dest='bq_table_name',
      type=str,
      required=False,
      help='Output BQ table to write results to',
      default=''
    )

class ParseLine(beam.DoFn):
  """A helper class which contains the logic to translate the file into a
    format BigQuery will accept."""

  def process(self, string_input):
    from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json
    import csv

    schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(self.schema)
    field_map = [f for f in schema.fields]
    items = csv.reader(string_input.split('\n'), delimiter=',')
    for item in items:
      values = [x.decode('utf8') for x in item]
      result = {}
      i = 0
      for value in values:
        result[field_map[i].name] = value
        i += 1
      return result

def run(argv=None):
  """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""
  known_args = PipelineOptions().view_as(TemplateOptions)
  pipeline_options = {
    'project': '<project-id>' ,
    'staging_location': '<gcs>/staging',
    'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
    'temp_location': '<gcs>/temp',
    'template_location': '<gcs>/csv-processor'
  }

  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    schemaPCollection = (p 
      | 'Read Schema' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(known_args.input_file_schema)
    )

    (p
      | 'Read Input File From GCS' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(known_args.input_file,
                                                skip_header_lines=1)
 ==>     | 'String to BigQuery Row' >> beam.ParDo(ParseLine(), schemaPCollection) <==
      | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            known_args.bq_table_name,
            schema=<NEED THE SCHEMA AS STRING>,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    )

    p.run().wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the schema file is in a known location in GCS, you can add a `ParDo` to your pipeline that directly reads it from GCS. For example, this can be done in a `start_bundle()` [1] implementation of your  `ParseLine` `DoFn` so that it only get invoked once per bundle (not per element). You can use Beam's `FileSystem` abstraction[2] if you need to abstract out the file-system that you use to store the schema file (not just GCS).

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L504
[2] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py

Comment: Thanks for answering @chamikara! I have few noobie questions on that approach. I am also using BigQuery sink as part of the final Dataflow step. Won't this approach cause an issue since the schema location is a runtime variable so on yielding the string, I will essentially get a generator for `parse_table_schema_from_json` function. I need the schema parameter as string for WriteToBigQuery api.

Comment: Actually you have the option to pass a callable as the schema and also optionally pass a side-input that can be used by this callable. See here for documentation on this: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2129c317794fc14aaa76330af73c6209faf38477/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L123

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am going to try this tomorrow. Appreciate your help, @chamikara!